# How to reset cache on a specific page by a given URL?

Tags: 9

In Drupal 7, I found a way to reset cache on a specific page with:

```
$url = url('<front>',  array('absolute' => TRUE));
cache_clear_all($url, 'cache_page');
```

What is the equivalent way in Drupal 9?

Comment: Using cache tags and contexts. Here's the docs https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-api and this is how to invalidate caches with a certain tag https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-tags#s-invalidating

Comment: Yes, there isn't a directly equivalent way in D9, as the way of handing caching was much improved between D7 and D8+.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I was adding a library to a specific page and it could be updated only through a configuration settings form, which would then reset the cache, so the library is properly updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
$url = Url::fromUserInput($custom_url);
  if ($url instanceof UrlInterface) {
    if ($url->isRouted()) {
      $nid = $url->getRouteParameters()['node'];
      /** @var \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node */
      $node = Node::load($nid);
      if ($node instanceof NodeInterface) {
        $tags = $node->getCacheTags();
        \Drupal::service('cache_tags.invalidator')->invalidateTags($tags);
      }
    }
  }
```